# User start daemon .pid Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, unicorn, permissions

Trying to start a unicorn daemon as a non-root user but failing hard.

**Unicorn gives the the following error:**

```
directory for pid=/var/run/sinatra_test/sinatra_test.pid not writable
```

**So I made the following:**

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/sinatra_test
sudo chown ruby:www-data /var/run/sinatra_test
sudo chmod g+w /var/run/sinatra_test
```

**ls -ld /var/run/sinatra_test returns:**

> drwxrwxr-x 2 ruby www-data 60 Oct 27 09:55 /var/run/sinatra_test

What am I missing? Still getting Permission denied errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you got some leftover with pid file (/var/run/sinatra_test/sinatra_test.pid).

Did you killed your app (kill -9 )?
If application is down, then verify if there is this pid file - if there is - please remove it. And retry to start it again.

Comment: I guess that was the error. I restarted the server and it works now. I didn't kill the app so I assume it still was running. Thanks.

Comment: Well it's always good to veryfiy it using ps aux | grep <application> and if you know on which port it does work - netstat -nlp | grep <port>. It's good habit.

Also - please restore folder permissions.